# How to add Tooltip Description for filter Box in Primefaces Datatable Column

Tags: primefaces

I have a dynamic generated Primefaces Datatable with some columns and each column have a simple filter box. I want put a tooltip for each filterBox.

i can add a tooltip for column header but i want tooltip for primefaces default filter box (not a custom filter).you can see column code below:

```
            <p:columns value="#{cc.columns}" id="dataTableColumn"  var="col" filterBy="#{col.filterExp}" sortBy="#{col.filterExp}" headerText="#{col.header}">
                <h:outputText value="#{data[col.position]}"
                              rendered="#{'java.math.BigDecimal'.equals(col.type) or 'java.lang.Integer'.equals(col.type) or 'java.lang.Long'.equals(col.type)}">
                    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="10"/>
                </h:outputText>
                <h:outputText value="#{data[col.position]}" rendered="#{'java.lang.String'.equals(col.type) or col.type.startsWith('serp3.entity.')}"/>
                <h:outputText converter="JalaliDateConverter" value="#{data[col.position]}" rendered="#{'java.util.Date'.equals(col.type)}"/>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{data[col.position]}" rendered="#{'java.lang.Boolean'.equals(col.type)}" disabled="true"/>
            </p:columns>
            <cc:insertFacet name="footer"/>
        </p:dataTable>
```

how i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `watermark` instead of tooltip. set a `StyleClass` for your `Column` and add a `<p:watermark>` for it like this:

```
 <p:columns value="#{cc.columns}" id="dataTableColumn" styleClass="watermark" var="col" filterBy="#{col.filterExp}" sortBy="#{col.filterExp}" headerText="#{col.header}"/>
                      <p:watermark for="@(.watermark)"  value="filter..."/>
```

it put a watermark for each filterbox.